# How to use ng-stomp in angular2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, stomp

How to use ng-stomp typedefinition provided by Definitely Typed Github repo in angular2 project

Here is my angular2 service : SocketService.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/globals/sockjs-client/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../typings/globals/ng-stomp/index.d.ts" />

import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';

export class SocketService {
    URL: string = 'http://127.0.0.1:9080/gs-guide-websocket';
    sock: any;
    stomp: ngStomp;
    handlers = {};

    private _opened: boolean = false;

    public open(): void {
        if (!this._opened) {
            //this.sock = new SockJS(this.URL);
            this.stomp.connect(this.URL).then(function(frame) {

            });
            console.log('Inside the call for the Socket connection');
            this._opened = true;
        }
    }

    public isOpen(): boolean {
        return this._opened;
    }

    public close(): void {
        if (this._opened) {
            this.sock.close();
            delete this.sock;
            this._opened = false;
        }
    }
}
```

My Type definitions installed using typings : 
a) Sockjs : index.d.ts

```
// Generated by typings
// Source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/50f81b23065f5c87b19f250c22979f93e1501cfd/sockjs-client/sockjs-client.d.ts
declare namespace __SockJSClient {
  interface BaseEvent extends Event {
    type: string;
  }

  interface OpenEvent extends BaseEvent {}

  interface CloseEvent extends BaseEvent {
    code: number;
    reason: string;
    wasClean: boolean;
  }

  interface MessageEvent extends BaseEvent {
    data: string;
  }

  interface SessionGenerator {
    (): string;
  }

  interface Options {
    server?: string;
    sessionId?: number | SessionGenerator;
    transports?: string | string[]
  }

  enum State {
    CONNECTING = 0, OPEN, CLOSING, CLOSED
  }

  interface SockJSClass extends EventTarget {
    readyState: State;
    protocol: string;
    url: string;
    onopen: (e: OpenEvent) => any;
    onclose: (e: CloseEvent) => any;
    onmessage: (e: MessageEvent) => any;
    send(data: any): void;
    close(code?: number, reason?: string): void;
  }
}

declare module 'sockjs-client' {
  import SockJSClass = __SockJSClient.SockJSClass;
  import Options = __SockJSClient.Options;
  import State = __SockJSClient.State;

  var SockJS: {
    new(url: string, _reserved?: any, options?: Options): SockJSClass;
    (url: string, _reserved?: any, options?: Options): SockJSClass;
    prototype: SockJSClass;
    CONNECTING: State;
    OPEN: State;
    CLOSING: State;
    CLOSED: State;
  };

  export = SockJS;
}
```

b) ng-stomp : index.d.ts

```
// Generated by typings
// Source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/0d29dd1f2e1ec36df21568d5f9da1263f3d099d7/ng-stomp/ng-stomp.d.ts
interface ngStomp {
        sock:any;
        stomp:any;
        debug:any;
        off: any;

        setDebug:(callback:Function)=> void;

        connect: (endpoint:string, headers?:Headers)=> angular.IHttpPromise<any>;

        disconnect: (callback:()=>void) => angular.IHttpPromise<any>;

        subscribe: (destination:string, callback:(payload:string, headers:Headers, res:Function)=>void, headers?:Headers, scope?:any) => any;

        unsubscribe: () => any;

        send: (destination:string, body:any, headers:Headers)=> any;

    }

     interface Headers {
        [key: string]: any;
    }
```

Following error is thrown when i try to connect to the server :

inline template:6:6 caused by: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined

Comment: I think that export is missing in the ng-stomp typedefinition.